# Tensorflow 2.0 - incorrect data shape for SparseCategoricalCrossentropy

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

When using `SparseCategoricalCrossentropy` loss I don't understand the error about the shape mismatch of the dataset.
The output seems to be in the correct form as per [SparseCategoricalCrossentropy](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r2.0/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/SparseCategoricalCrossentropy) :
Input : [7 1]
Output: [7 3]
Where batch size is 7.

My environment currently runs:
python 3.7.4
**tensorflow 2.0.0-rc0**
numpy 1.17.2
pandas 0.24.2

```py
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
InvalidArgumentError                      Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-fe1cc3e1dca1> in <module>
     47 print(model.summary())
     48 
---> 49 model.fit(train.batch(BATCH_SIZE), epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=2)
     50 model.evaluate(train, steps=None, verbose=1)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing, **kwargs)
    732         max_queue_size=max_queue_size,
    733         workers=workers,
--> 734         use_multiprocessing=use_multiprocessing)
    735 
    736   def evaluate(self,

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in fit(self, model, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_freq, **kwargs)
    322                 mode=ModeKeys.TRAIN,
    323                 training_context=training_context,
--> 324                 total_epochs=epochs)
    325             cbks.make_logs(model, epoch_logs, training_result, ModeKeys.TRAIN)
    326 

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2.py in run_one_epoch(model, iterator, execution_function, dataset_size, batch_size, strategy, steps_per_epoch, num_samples, mode, training_context, total_epochs)
    121         step=step, mode=mode, size=current_batch_size) as batch_logs:
    122       try:
--> 123         batch_outs = execution_function(iterator)
    124       except (StopIteration, errors.OutOfRangeError):
    125         # TODO(kaftan): File bug about tf function and errors.OutOfRangeError?

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/keras/engine/training_v2_utils.py in execution_function(input_fn)
     84     # `numpy` translates Tensors to values in Eager mode.
     85     return nest.map_structure(_non_none_constant_value,
---> 86                               distributed_function(input_fn))
     87 
     88   return execution_function

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    437         # Lifting succeeded, so variables are initialized and we can run the
    438         # stateless function.
--> 439         return self._stateless_fn(*args, **kwds)
    440     else:
    441       canon_args, canon_kwds = \

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   1820     """Calls a graph function specialized to the inputs."""
   1821     graph_function, args, kwargs = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
-> 1822     return graph_function._filtered_call(args, kwargs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
   1823 
   1824   @property

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _filtered_call(self, args, kwargs)
   1139          if isinstance(t, (ops.Tensor,
   1140                            resource_variable_ops.BaseResourceVariable))),
-> 1141         self.captured_inputs)
   1142 
   1143   def _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager=None):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in _call_flat(self, args, captured_inputs, cancellation_manager)
   1222     if executing_eagerly:
   1223       flat_outputs = forward_function.call(
-> 1224           ctx, args, cancellation_manager=cancellation_manager)
   1225     else:
   1226       gradient_name = self._delayed_rewrite_functions.register()

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/function.py in call(self, ctx, args, cancellation_manager)
    509               inputs=args,
    510               attrs=("executor_type", executor_type, "config_proto", config),
--> 511               ctx=ctx)
    512         else:
    513           outputs = execute.execute_with_cancellation(

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/eager/execute.py in quick_execute(op_name, num_outputs, inputs, attrs, ctx, name)
     65     else:
     66       message = e.message
---> 67     six.raise_from(core._status_to_exception(e.code, message), None)
     68   except TypeError as e:
     69     keras_symbolic_tensors = [

~/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/six.py in raise_from(value, from_value)

InvalidArgumentError:  assertion failed: [] [Condition x == y did not hold element-wise:] [x (loss/dense_3_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/Shape_1:0) = ] [7 1] [y (loss/dense_3_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/strided_slice:0) = ] [7 3]
     [[node loss/dense_3_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/assert_equal/Assert/Assert (defined at /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/python/framework/ops.py:1751) ]] [Op:__inference_distributed_function_2031]

Function call stack:
distributed_function
```

With tensorflow=2.0.0-beta0:

```
InvalidArgumentError:  logits and labels must have the same first dimension, got logits shape [34,3] and labels shape [2]
     [[node loss/dense_2_loss/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits/SparseSoftmaxCrossEntropyWithLogits (defined at <ipython-input-3-4fa88a5fad5e>:70) ]] [Op:__inference_keras_scratch_graph_5038]
```

Can someone explain or point me in the correct direction?

Thanks

The following code reproduces the error:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import random
import tensorflow as tf

INPUT_SHAPE=[3, 5]
NUM_POINTS=20
BATCH_SIZE=7
EPOCHS=4

def data_gen(num=10, in_shape=[5, 3]):
    for i in range(num):
        x = np.random.rand(in_shape[0], in_shape[1])
        y = random.randint(0,2)
        yield x, y

train = tf.data.Dataset.from_generator(
    generator=data_gen,
    output_types=(tf.float32, tf.int32),
    args=([NUM_POINTS, INPUT_SHAPE])
)

def create_model(input_shape):
    model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(100, activation="tanh",input_shape=input_shape),        
        tf.keras.layers.Dense(3, activation="softmax", kernel_regularizer= tf.keras.regularizers.l2(0.001))
    ])
    return model

model = create_model(input_shape=INPUT_SHAPE)

model.compile(
    optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=1e-4, clipvalue=1.0),
    loss= tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy())
print(model.summary())

model.fit(train.batch(BATCH_SIZE), epochs=EPOCHS, verbose=2)
model.evaluate(train, steps=None, verbose=1)
```

Model summary:

> Model: "sequential_1"
>   _________________________________________________________________ Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #
>   ================================================================= dense_2 (Dense)              (None, 3, 100)            600
>   _________________________________________________________________ dense_3 (Dense)              (None, 3, 3)              303
>   ================================================================= Total params: 903 Trainable params: 903 Non-trainable params: 0
>
> ---

Comment: You said this happens with SparseCategoricalCrossentropy - but it would be strange to not get this same error with other (categorical) loss function, have you tried it with others which are working? What is the shape of your X and y? It would be helpful to see your model.summary() too

Comment: Is your issue resolved. Tried reproducing your code and it resulted in the error, `    ValueError: Input 0 of layer sequential is incompatible with the layer: its rank is undefined, but the layer requires a defined rank.`, Tensorflow Version 2.3.